# CSS Sprites on Table TD

Tags: html, css, menu, interactive, sprite

I want to make a menu with CSS sprites but there's not ONE browser on the planet that can read it. My problem can be found [here](http://jocolina.com).

My CSS is:

```
#menuMusica{
  width:340px;
  height:190px;
  background:url('images/menuMusic.png') 0px 0px;
}

#menuMusica a:hover{
  background: url('images/menuMusic.png') 0px -190px;
}
```

And my HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
  <table cellspacing=100px>
    <tr>
        <td id="menuMusica" onmouseover="soundGuitar();">
        <a href="javascript:;" onclick="alerter('This site is under construction! Come back soon. You can always follow me on Facebook and Twitter!');"><img  src="images/menuP.png" border=0></a>
      </td>
        <td id="menuPhoto" onmouseover="soundPhoto();">
        <a href="photo/index.html"><img src="images/menuP.png" border=0></a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: tables and sprites don't mix well in my experience. Tables should not be used at all in your case...

Answer (score 1):

Change `#menuMusica a:hover {` to `#menuMusica:hover {`.

Comment: From what I understand, that won't work on older IE broswers.  They only render :hover css on `a` elements.

Comment: @DMoses Tested in IE7 and works fine. Don't know about IE6 (don't care much either)

Comment: Thanks a lot to you all, finally did the change between a:hover to hover and worked just fine (with a little tweaks).

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the 'mouseout' background is applied to your `td` element, but your 'mouseover' background is applied to the `a` element inside of it. Since the `a` element doesn't fill up all the available vertical space, you can't see the rollover.

The quickest solution is to add `display: block;` to the styles for your `a` elements.

If you want to be consistent, you should also move the `background` CSS property from `#menuMusica` to `#menuMusica a`.

Comment: Also add height/width 100% and remove the img sub-element

Comment: @DMoses Those changes don't make any apparent difference in my browser, although they will improve load time slightly.